# Javafx. Удаление строки из TableView и MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных, javafx, tableview

Нужно реализовать удаление строки из базы данных при вводе номера этой строки (id_depositor) в текстовое поле id_depositorField.
Добавление новых записей в таблицу работает, при удалении же ничего не происходит. Как это можно исправить?

Класс Depositors:

```
package sample;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Depositors {

@FXML
private ResourceBundle resources;

@FXML
private URL location;

@FXML
private Button backButton;

@FXML
private TableView<depositorTable> depositor_Table;

@FXML
private TableColumn<depositorTable, Integer> id_depositor;

@FXML
private TableColumn<depositorTable, String> FIO;

@FXML
private TableColumn<depositorTable, String> address;

@FXML
private TableColumn<depositorTable, String> phone_number;

@FXML
private TableColumn<depositorTable, String> passport_data;

@FXML
private Button addButton;

@FXML
private Button changeButton;

@FXML
private Button deleteButton;

@FXML
private TextField id_depositorField;

@FXML
private TextField fioField;

@FXML
private TextField addressField;

@FXML
private TextField phone_numberField;

@FXML
private TextField passport_dataField;

ObservableList<depositorTable> oblist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@FXML
void initialize() {

    addButton.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
        signUpNewDepositor();
        oblist.clear();
        addFunction();
    });


    deleteButton.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
        deleteChosenDepositor();
        oblist.clear();
        addFunction();
    });

    addFunction();

    id_depositor.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id_depositor"));
    FIO.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("FIO"));
    address.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("address"));
    phone_number.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("phone_number"));
    passport_data.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("passport_data"));


    depositor_Table.setItems(oblist);
}

// вывод таблицы
public void addFunction() {
    try {
        Connection con = DatabaseHandler.getConnection();
        ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM depositor");

        while (rs.next()) {
            oblist.add(new depositorTable(rs.getString("id_depositor"), rs.getString("FIO"),
                    rs.getString("address"), rs.getString("phone_number"),
                    rs.getString("passport_data")));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// добавление записи в таблицу
private void signUpNewDepositor() {
    DatabaseHandler dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler();

    String FIO = fioField.getText();
    String address = addressField.getText();
    String phone_number = phone_numberField.getText();
    String passport_data = passport_dataField.getText();

    depositorTable depositor = new depositorTable(FIO, address, phone_number, passport_data);

    dbHandler.signUpDepositor(depositor);
}

// удаление записи из таблицы
private void deleteChosenDepositor() {
    DatabaseHandler dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler();

    String id_depositor = id_depositorField.getText();

    depositorTable depositor = new depositorTable(id_depositor);

    dbHandler.deleteDepositor(depositor);
}
}
```

Класс DatabaseHandler:

```
public void deleteDepositor(depositorTable depositor) {
String delete = "DELETE FROM " + Const.DEPOSITOR_TABLE + " WHERE " + Const.DEPOSITOR_ID + " = ?";

try {
    PreparedStatement prSt = getDbConnection().prepareStatement(delete);
    prSt.setString(1, depositor.getId_depositor());

    prSt.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: *при удалении же ничего не происходит* Не бывает. Если запрос добирается до MySQL, обратно обязательно придёт либо информация о выполнении (и количестве записей, на которые запрос повлиял), либо сообщение об ошибке выполнения запроса. Именно это и нужно вывести и по нему смотреть. А ещё неплохо бы посмотреть, как именно выглядит текст запроса - после всех сложений и подготовок с подстановками.

Comment: @Akina помогла передача переменной id_depositor из функции deleteChosenDepositor() как параметр в функцию deleteDepositor(String id) класса DatabaseHandler. Спасибо.